# Rewrite bad url extention to .html in NGINX

Tags: nginx, regex

A while back I made a mistake writing my urls and Google has them cached in old sitemaps. This is creating a ton of 404 errors in WMT that I need to clean up with a solid rewrite. I currently use the map module and rewrite each product individually.

Example:

```
/product1html/ /product1.html;
```

The mistake being in bold here: http://domain/productname**html/**

The error here is I initially forgot the . before html and had an / at the end.

How can I rewrite the url to be `http://domain/productname.html` for every url that looks like `/productnamehtml/`.

Comment: Do you need only one particular url?

Comment: No it needs to be a wildcard match for every product which I can't work out the regex for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The rewrite will look like this:

```
rewrite ^(.*[^.])html/?$ $1.html permanent;
```

Or you might want to place it into a location:

```
location ~* ^(?<product>.*[^.])html/?$ {
    return 301 $product.html;
}
```

Explanation: Both regex are identical, except the latter has a named capture `product`. We look for any sequence that ends in a non-dot followed by `html`, followed by (optional) `/`. Everything before the `html` is captured.

Comment: This answer fixed my issue right away. Now I need to look over the regex and understand why it works. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @Kanyin Added a short explanation..